# Apache/IIS relay

Tags: apache, iis-7, webserver

In my LAN I have two web servers, one Apache Linux Server (Debian) and one Microsoft Web Server (IIS7).

Apache has three webpages, i.e., apache01.com apache02.com and apache03.com and IIS7 has microsoft01.com and microsoft02.com

My question is:

- To access from outside LAN to any domain, what is better? NAT port 80 to IIS7 or to Apache?
- And then, How to delay from Apache/IIS7 to IIS7/Apache the domains it doesn't manage?

I've never done this, so I ask because it could be a lot of thinks I'm not seeing.

I don't need a full procedure, only a guidelines to continue researching.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server)

The key is IIS URL Rewrite Module and Reverse proxy